# How do you enable a plotly tabs with callback?

Tags: python, tabs, plotly

How would you enable a tab by using callouts? As an example below, I have two tabs where the second one 'tab-2' is disabled.

```
from dash import Dash, DiskcacheManager, CeleryManager, dcc, html,no_update, ctx, dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Tabs(id="tabs-styled-with-inline", parent_className='custom-tabs',value='tab-1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Class Stats', 
            value='tab-1', 
            style=tab_style, 
            selected_style=tab_selected_style, 
            disabled=False,
            children=[something_layout]),
        dcc.Tab(label='Class Analysis', 
            value='tab-2', 
            style=tab_style, 
            selected_style=tab_selected_style, 
            disabled=True,
            children=[something_layout2]),
    ], colors={
        "background": "#434343"
    },style=tabs_styles),
    html.Div(id='tabs-content-inline'),
    dcc.Store(id='current-data'),
    ],
)
```

I thought it would be something like this below:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("tab-2", "disabled"),
    Input('current-data', 'data'),
)
def enable_tab(current_df):
    return False
```

But I am not getting anywhere with it. I believe it has to do something with the tabs ID being "tabs-styled-with-inline" and I have to maybe specify that the tab-2 is part of that ID. Could someone show me how this works?

-----EDIT------
For clarification, the `enable_tab` function should be triggered whenever the `current-data` gets populated or refreshed..I've added it as a dcc.Store element in the example above.

Comment: When should the callback start to work? or what should trigger the callback?

Comment: it's some extra long analysis that's being done on the server side. Whenever that 'current-data' is refreshed, the tab-2 should be enabled.